# Row-Reduced-Echelon-Form with Equation Parameters for Consistent Systems

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I often do [row-reduced-echelon-form (RREF)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EchelonForm.html) calculations that involve parameters using the [*RowReduce*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RowReduce.html) command.

Most times, I want to know which parameters make the system consistent.

For example:

```
 RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3, a}, {4, 5, 6, a^2}, {7, 8, 9, a^3}}]
```

Mathematica reduces this to its lowest form, which results in an inconsistent system because the last row is {0,0,0,1}.

However, if you look at the details of the the steps it takes (using WA with rref {{1, 2, 3, a}, {4, 5, 6, a^2}, {7, 8, 9, a^3}}), it shows the point where you could see that choosing $a = 0$ or $a = 1$ would produce a consistent system with infinite solutions. Either of these values for $a$ makes the last row of the rref {0,0,0,0}.

Is there a way to get Mathematica to show this reduction without losing that important fact  or to state which values of the parameters make the system consistent? Maybe I should be using a different command or approach.

It is also interesting that rref is able to successfully find the result for this two parameter example:

```
 RowReduce[{{a, b, 1, 1},{1, a b, 1, b},{1, b, b, 1}}]
```

Comment: Quick remark: If you hit the matrix with `LUDecomposition` you will see a relevant matrix element (row 3, col 4) with zeros of `a=0` and `a=1`. Not sure how general or reliable this germ of an idea might be though.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I will give it a go, thank you for the hint! Regards

Comment: This should give useful info: `Reduce[{{1, 2, 3, a}, {4, 5, 6, a^2}, {7, 8, 9, a^3}}.{x, y, z, 
    w} == {0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z, w}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Putting in a check for `a` in the `ZeroTest` lets Mathematica be aware that it can be zero sometimes:

```
RowReduce[{{1, 2, 3, a}, {4, 5, 6, a^2}, {7, 8, 9, a^3}}, 
  ZeroTest -> (! FreeQ[#, a] || PossibleZeroQ[#] &)
  ] //Last // Simplify
(* {0, 0, 0, -3 (-1 + a)^2 a} *)
```

But note that it doesn't get normalized down to 1 in cases when it's non-zero, so it's no longer in echelon form.

```
%/.a->4
{0, 0, 0, -108}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with:

```
MatrixForm[A = {{1, 2, 3, a}, {4, 5, 6, a^2}, {7, 8, 9, a^3}}]
```

Which gives the result:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & a\\
4 & 5 & 6 & a^2\\
7 & 8 & 9 & a^3
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then:

```
r1 = A[[1]];
r2 = A[[2]];
r3 = A[[3]];
```

Then:

```
MatrixForm[A = {r1, r2 - 4 r1, r3 - 7 r1}]
```

Which gives the result:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & a\\
0 & -3 & -6 & -4a+a^2\\
0 & -6 & -12 & -7a+a^3
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then:

```
r1 = A[[1]];
r2 = A[[2]];
r3 = A[[3]];
```

And finally:

```
MatrixForm[A = {r1, r2, r3 - 2 r2}] // Simplify
```

Which gives the result:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & a\\
0 & -3 & -6 & -4a+a^2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & (-1+a)^2a
\end{bmatrix}$$